# TextArea .SetValue is not working with large amount of data

Tags: html

I'm sending binary data to a TextArea in a webpage viewed in a COM Object, i can't set the value of the text area when the data amount is large, it's not working, although when I paste the data from clipboard into the TextArea everything works fine.

Do you know anything about that?

Comment: share some codes that you tried.

Comment: The HTML file is:

<HTML><BODY><form method="post" name="form" action="index.php">     <textarea name="data" style="width: 220px; height: 35px;"></textarea><br />     <input name="id" type="text"/><br/>     <input name = "Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit Encoded Command" style="font-size: x-small; width: 150px;"/> </form>

Then I use AutoIt to read a file as binary then send the data to the TextArea:

For better view of code:
http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/155735-ieformelementsetvalue-not-working-with-large-data/